# How to Compute of Sum of Each Rows and the Total Sum of an Array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, sum, percentage

When I compute the **total Sum** it is **not calculating the total of all array** instead it prints a random number, when I **separate** them I **cannot get the percentage** properly I need help

Sum is for the Sum of **Columns**
TSum is for the **total Sum** of Array

```
TSum=0;
for(rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++)
{     
    Sum=0;      
    for(columns = 0; columns < 4+1; columns++)
    {
        Sum += arr[columns][rows];
        TSum += arr[rows][columns];
        Percnt = Sum/TSum*100;
        
    }
        l++;
        printf("Candidate #%d Total:\t %d\t Percentage: %.0f%%\t Sum Rows: %d\n",l, Sum,Percnt,TSum);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use TSum, its value change for each row : it contains the sum of the nth first rows. If you want to get the total sum of the array you need to use it after all rows has been read. To prevent looping twice in all array you could have an array for the sum of each row and when the row loop is finished loop on this array to print the percent values.

```
TSum=0;
for(rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++)
{     
    Sum=0;      
    for(columns = 0; columns < 4+1; columns++)
    {
        Sum += arr[columns][rows];
        TSum += arr[rows][columns];
        Percnt = Sum/TSum*100;
    
    }
    // here Sum contains sum of all columns for one row
    // here TSum contains sum of all columns of all rows from 0 to rows
    l++;
    printf("Candidate #%d Total:\t %d\t Percentage: %.0f%%\t Sum Rows: %d\n",l, Sum,Percnt,TSum);
}  
// Here TSum contains the sum of all columns of all rows
```

What I suggested :

```
int Sum[5];
TSum=0;
for(rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++)
{     
    Sum[rows]=0;      
    for(columns = 0; columns < 4+1; columns++)
    {
        Sum[rows] += arr[columns][rows];
    }
    TSum += Sum[rows]; // only one operation per rows
}  

for(rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++)
{     
    Percnt = Sum[rows]/TSum*100;
    l++;
    printf("Candidate #%d Total:\t %d\t Percentage: %.0f%%\t Sum Rows: %d\n",l, Sum,Percnt,TSum);
}
```